# Steps needed to configure Artemis SSL client authentication using trusted CA Certificates

Tags: activemq-artemis

According to the ActiveMQ Artemis documents it is possible to do 2 way TLS aka client certificate authentication using a trusted CA. See extract below.

Two-way TLS uses the same `sslEnabled`, `keyStorePath`, and `keyStorePassword` properties as one-way TLS, but it adds `needClientAuth=true` to tell the client it should present a certificate of its own. For example:

```xml
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=../etc/broker.keystore;keyStorePassword=1234!;needClientAuth=true</acceptor>
```

This configuration assumes that the client's certificate is signed by a trusted provider. If the client's certificate is not signed by a trusted provider (e.g. it is self-signed) then the server needs to import the client's certificate into a trust-store and configure the `acceptor` with `trustStorePath` and `trustStorePassword`, e.g.:

```xml
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=../etc/broker.keystore;keyStorePassword=1234!</acceptor>
```

My requirements at the moment are full 2 way SSL with client getting their cert from our CA. According to the docs my understanding is that we would not need to add the keys of client to the trust store every time a user signs up. NOTE: we are doing this on the AMQP protocol.

On a high level the setup would be:

1. Install CA into JRE `cacerts` keystore.
2. Create a signing request for the broker.
3. CA creates certificate for broker.
4. Install broker certificate into keystore (e.g. `etc/broker-certs.p12`)
5. Client creates cert signing request
6. CA creates client certificate.
7. Client presents certificate when connecting.

Before I go down the rabbit hole of SSL I wanted to check that if what I am trying to achieve is even possible?

I tried the `ssl-enabled-dual-authentication` example  however it is throwing an exception on launch of the client.

```
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException: AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null
```

**FOR JDK 11+ Users:** To try out the ssl-enabled-dual-authenticaion example you will need to recreate all the certificates. The comments sections has some more details.

Comment: You missed configuring `needClientAuth=true` as well as `trustStorePath` and `trustStorePassword` in your self-signed `acceptor` example.

Comment: I just ran the `ssl-enabled-dual-authentication` on the current `master` branch as well as 2.17.0, 2.16.0, 2.15.0, 2.14.0, 2.13.0, & 2.12.0 and they all completed successfully with no exceptions. Perhaps something in your environment is messed up.

Comment: Do I need to create an instance before running the examples? I just unzipped it and did a mvn verify. Running on Ubuntu for what it is worth.

Comment: You don't need to manually create an instance. Using `mvn verify` will automatically create any necessary instances. I'm on Ubuntu as well, and I also just unzipped and ran `mvn clean verify`.

Comment: I forgot I am running JDK 11 as I am doing camel 3 work and JDK 8 is best effort only. When I ran `mvn -Prelease install` it reported the following:`[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
JDK 8 is required when building the release`. That is ok. I will use the example and run a local instance as I can stay on JDK11 for now.

Comment: I switched to JDK 11 and I was able to reproduce the failure. I got `AMQ222208: SSL handshake failed for client from /127.0.0.1:49280: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Empty client certificate chain.` which eventually let to the `AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null`. I just needed to regenerate the SSL resources for the example using the commands from the readme and everything worked fine after that.

Comment: Yeah that works a treat. Thanks mate appreciate the time you spend helping people. WIsh I could upvote you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and your "high level" steps look good.

It may be helpful to look at the [`ssl-enabled-dual-authentication` example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/examples/features/standard/ssl-enabled-dual-authentication/readme.md) that ships with the broker. It demonstrates how to configure mutual authentication using self-signed certificates including the `keytool` commands for creating, importing, & exporting the various SSL resources. This is slightly different than your use-case which involves using a CA, but the process is essentially equivalent. The real difference is that instead of adding the client's cert to the broker's truststore and vice versa you're adding the CA's cert to all the JVMs.

Comment: Okay cool thanks I had a look at the example but it does not run  see my edit above.

Comment: Will figure it out as long as it is possible.